# N percent used in the SQL query does not return actual results

Tags: sql, sql-server, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to take 10% of the customers from the table like below ,

```
select top 10 percent  t1.EMAIL
from customers t1
```

The output I get is all the records AND NOT 10%. I am not getting what I am doing wrong here? Can anyone help me

This is the target Data Extension used in Salesforce Marketing cloud and action is overwrite

[image]

Comment: I assume you are using SQL Server. If not, please let me know.

Comment: yes right sql server

Comment: Please update your question with details about the target data extension.  Are you doing an update or overwrite?

Comment: Hi Adam just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b6f39/2) that selects the top 10% of 20 items. It successfully returned 2 items, as expected.

## Schema

```
create table foo(id int primary key);
insert into foo(id) values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9),
(10),
(11),
(12),
(13),
(14),
(15),
(16),
(17),
(18),
(19),
(20);
```

## Selection

```
select top 10 percent *
from foo;
```

## Result

[image]

## Possible causes of your issue

- it is possible that you have 0 items
- it is possible that you do not execute what you think you execute (forgot to rebuild an app or something of the like)
- it is possible that your actual query was modified for the purpose of the question to avoid disclosing information

## If this answer still didn't help

then you may want to create a SQL Fiddle in which you have a reproducible problem. You may also share further information as about what the `customers` table is like, its structure, its size, etc.

Comment: You are right this works in fiddle. But I when I am running this in Salesforce marketing cloud which uses SQL server I am getting this issue. Earlier the same query used to work

Comment: Is there any alternative where I can take the 10% using any formula in a simple  way

Comment: @u89716 yes, there is an alternative. You could `select count(*) / 10` into a variable before your selection and use that variable in your `top` clause, see https://intellipaat.com/community/4388/dynamic-select-top-var-in-sql-server

Comment: I know that the query is right and works perfectly in fiddle but unfortunately it returns me wrong results in marketing loud

Comment: @u89716 did you try the idea with the variable and did it fail? If so, how? Did you get an error?